# library design - pattern to restrict usage of "intern" classes/methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, visibility

I stumbled upon a small library which has some classes in four packages and one basic class that should be used by who ever will use this library.

I had to review this library and suggested, that the access to some classes and methods should be restricted as the user should only see methods/classes that he really should use. In this case it should be one class with a few methods that can be called.

While my suggestion just popped into my mind, I couldn't get a real solution on how to do that.

The first ugly idea was: Put the public class in package `a` and everything else in package `a.b` which isn't a good idea.

The package structure prevent the `protected` modifier as classes in package `a.b` need to call methods from a class in package `a.c`. So is there a pattern that can be used to prevent that someone is instantiating a class inside `a.b` and call their public methods?

If the description of the problem wasn't good enough, feel free to ask in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put classes that you don't want other people to see with default modifier ( basically with no modifier at all ).  This will make them package-private.

All classes inside the package will be able to see and use them, but nobody outside the library would be able to instantiate and use them without reflection cheats.

This implies that library should use a single package.

Comment: We are doing that as this might be the best work/effect relation also @dimitrisli has also a good solution (+1 on both)

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't understand your sentence about the protected access modifier (aren't `b` and `c` already packaged?) here are two suggestions:

- Reduce or manage object creations through factory methods
- If as you say the main class is accessing stuff from the other packages then most likely it can be treated as various types. If that's the case you could create different interfaces that correspond to the functional obligations of each package say `InterfacePackA`, `InterfacePackB` that your main class would implement and therefore the client code would hold your main class under the interface type of preference reducing this way the scope and functionality of the quite generic and bottlenecked main class.

Answer (score 0):

Put the classes that people should not use as `private static`classes inside the main class.

Comment: We talk about 98% of the library classes. This is not a maintainable solution as the size of the library might grow rapidly. Basically I want to hide all but one class to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Java has no way of stopping public classes in a jar from being called.  If you hide what the other classes do by obfuscating them, then you could give out your jar and only expose certain classes that you wanted used. This would not make it impossible to use your public classes, but would take more work than it is probably worth.